# managing brackets through dot files

Tags: adobe-brackets

I'm a Vim user. Just started using Brackets for HTML and CSS. Just wondering is there a way to manage extensions and settings through dot files something similar to .vimrc and vundle, hence I can reproduce the same brackets environment in stroke of a command in new machine.

Answer (score 0):

Preferences are stored in JSON files which you can copy between machines. Extensions are simply folders in a fixed location, so you'll need to copy your whole extensions folder to a different machine in order to have the same extensions there.

To locate these files:

1. Select *Help > Show Extensions Folder* in the menu
2. Copy the `user` folder to the same place on another computer to sync the set of installed extensions
3. Go up to the parent folder
4. Copy `brackets.json` to sync preferences
5. There's also a `state.json` in this folder, which stores things like recently opened projects and the size of resizable panels. It might not work very well to copy that over, since the recent projects may not exist at the same location on the other computer, the screen size may differ, etc. But if you're adventurous you can try copying it too – worst case, just delete it to reset all that stuff :-)

Btw, if you'd like to have a smoother way to automatically sync settings & extensions across different copies of Brackets, you can upvote these items on the Brackets feature backlog: [preferences sync](https://trello.com/c/RYbXZXn1/368-settings-preferences-synchronization-across-brackets-copies-8), [extensions sync](https://trello.com/c/Y29lYIEL/889-sync-extensions-from-one-computer-to-another).